# How can we ignore the comma's inside barces while converting csv into bean or string array in java

Tags: java, csv, java-8, opencsv

Below is the sample CSV file, Im trying to convert to java bean/string[],

```
ID,NAME,DEP_DETAILS,REG_NO
P7-3001,JOHN,{"head_dep":"[{\"dep\":\"CS\",\"update_time\":\"2021-06-17T07:29:40.800Z\"}]","LN":false},009988
RT-9008,RIK,{"head_dep":"OPEN","dep_type":"S7"},889912
```

In the sample data, I want to read DEP_DETAILS in whole by ignoring comma's inside braces,

DEP_DETAILS is {"head_dep":"[{"dep":"CS","update_time":"2021-06-17T07:29:40.800Z"}]","LN":false} in 1st row and {"head_dep":"OPEN","dep_type":"S7"} in 2nd row

so for example expected output of the 1st row will be,

```
- [0] = P7-3001,JOHN
- [1] = JOHN
- [2] = {"head_dep":"[{\"dep\":\"CS\",\"update_time\":\"2021-06-17T07:29:40.800Z\"}]","LN":false}
- [3] = 889912
```

how can I ignore the comma's inside the brace and take whole as string.

Is there any possibilities using openCsv or any?

Comment: That isn't legal "standard CSV" format, so you will need to find a parser for it, or write your own.  If you know the embedded JSON is always (and only) in the third field, a simple string splitter that can find the leading `,{` and trailing `},` followed by a number should work.  Then remove the JSON and parse the rest with OpenCSV.

Comment: But a better solution is to fix whatever generated that input to generate **valid** CSV; e.g. using OpenCSV rather some [crufty](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crufty) hand written code or script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse input strings as the ones you supplied as examples then you **could** use methods similar to the ones below:

```
/**
 * By default this method with split a String based on the supplied delimiter 
 * ignoring that delimiter within parentheses. If you want to ignore splitting 
 * within other bracket types then supply those bracket types within the optional 
 * <b>bracketTypes</b> parameter.<br><br>
 * 
 * Works against the following bracket types:<pre>
 * 
 *     {@code ( ), { }, [ ], < > }</pre>
 * 
 * @param inputString (String) The string to split.<br>
 * 
 * @param delimiter (String) The delimiter to split the String by.<br>
 * 
 * @param bracketTypes (String) Each bracket type supplied must be the open bracket 
 * and close bracket [ie: "{}"  or "{}", "()" ].<br>
 * 
 * @return (String[] Array)
 */
public static String[] splitExceptInBrackets(String inputString, String delimiter,
                                             String... bracketTypes) {
    // *** This method will not take care of Nested Brackets!
    // Based on the following RegEx:  ",(?![^\[\(]*[$\]\)])" which
    // is modified and built depending upon which bracket or bracket 
    // types are supplied.

    String[] exceptions = {"()"};
    if (bracketTypes.length > 0) {
        
        exceptions = Arrays.copyOf(bracketTypes, bracketTypes.length);
    }

    // Create the regex for split() method
    String splitExpression = delimiter + "(?![^";
    String sStrg = "", eStrg = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < exceptions.length; i++) {
        String ob = exceptions[i].trim().substring(0, 1);
        sStrg += "\\" + ob;
        // Make sure this particular Bracket Type is properly paired.
        if (!areBracketsBalanced(inputString, ob)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("\nsplitExceptInBrackets() Method Error!\n"
                    + "A broken pair of " + exceptions[i] + " brackets detected in String!\n");
        }
        eStrg += "\\" + exceptions[i].trim().substring(1, 2);
    }
    splitExpression += sStrg + "]*[$" + eStrg + "])";
    return inputString.split(splitExpression);
}
```

The following method is used by the **splitExceptInBrackets()** method so to ensure brackets within the supplied input string are properly balanced.

```
/**
 * This method will return either true of false if the supplied bracket type
 * is balanced (contains a Open Bracket and a related Close Bracket). If no
 * optional Bracket Type is supplied then the default Parentheses is
 * assumed.<br><br>
 * <p>
 * There can be any number of the same brackets within the supplied input
 * string.<br>
 *
 * @param inputString (String) The string to process.<br>
 *
 * @param bracketType (Optional - String - Default is Parentheses ()) Only
 *                    one of four bracket types can be supplied to this
 *                    parameter and you are only required to supply one half
 *                    of the set, either the Open Bracket or the Close
 *                    Bracket. There is no requirement to supply both. The
 *                    four different types of brackets that can be supplied are:<pre>
 *
 *      ()  Parentheses or Round Brackets
 *      []  Square or Box Brackets
 *      {}  Braces or Curly Brackets
 *     {@code <>}  Angle or Chevron Brackets</pre>
 *
 * @return (Boolean) This method will return either true of false if the
 *         supplied bracket type is balanced.
 */
public static boolean areBracketsBalanced(String inputString, String... bracketType) {
    boolean matched = false;
    String openBracket = "(";
    String closeBracket = ")";
    String bType = openBracket;
    if (bracketType.length > 0) {
        bType = bracketType[0].substring(0, 1);
    }

    switch (bType) {
        case "(":
        case ")":
            openBracket = "(";
            closeBracket = ")";
            break;
        case "[":
        case "]":
            openBracket = "[";
            closeBracket = "]";
            break;
        case "{":
        case "}":
            openBracket = "{";
            closeBracket = "}";
            break;
        case "<":
        case ">":
            openBracket = "<";
            closeBracket = ">";
            break;
        default:
    }

    // See if there are equal pairs of brackets
    // within the supplied input string...
    int oBrackets = 0;
    int cBrackets = 0;
    if (openBracket.equals("[")) {
        oBrackets = inputString.replaceAll("[^\\" + openBracket + "]", "").length();
        cBrackets = inputString.replaceAll("[^\\" + closeBracket + "]", "").length();
    }
    else {
        oBrackets = inputString.replaceAll("[^" + openBracket + "]", "").length();
        cBrackets = inputString.replaceAll("[^" + closeBracket + "]", "").length();
    }
    if (oBrackets == cBrackets) {
        matched = true;
    }
    return matched;
}
```

Both methods make use of [Regular Expressions](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx). You can use [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/) to see what these expressions do.

How you might use the **splitExceptInBrackets()** method:

```
String fileLine = "P7-3001,JOHN,{\"head_dep\":\"[{\"dep\":\"CS\",\"update_time\":\"2021-06-17T07:29:40.800Z\"}]\",\"LN\":false},009988";
String[] lineParts = splitExceptInBrackets(fileLine, ",", "{}");
for (String parts : lineParts) {
    System.out.println(parts);
}
```

The output to console window would be:

```
P7-3001
JOHN
{"head_dep":"[{"dep":"CS","update_time":"2021-06-17T07:29:40.800Z"}]","LN":false}
009988
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me describe your need again. You want to parse each JSON string containing commas in a non-standard-format CSV file into a whole string. It is rather long to do the parsing in Java.

It is simple to get the job done in SPL, the open-source Java package. Only one line of code is enough:

| + | 1 |
| --- | --- |
|  | =file("json.csv").import@cpt(ID,NAME,DEP_DETAILS:string,REG_NO) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as parseCsv.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…    
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");   
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");    
st=con.prepareCall("call parseCsv ()");    
st.execute();    
…
```

Or execute the SPL string within a Java program in the way of executing a SQL statement:

```
…    
st = con.prepareStatement("==file(\"json.csv\").import@cpt(ID,NAME,
     DEP_DETAILS:string,REG_NO)");
st.execute();    
…
```